# Why doesn't the rotation of a curl equal the curl of a rotation, if both curl and the rotation are linear.

Tags: vector-analysis, rotations

I was trying to get the curl of some rotated vector field $\nabla \times R_{ij}n_j(\vec{r})$.

I tried taking ou the rotation matrix $R$.

$$R_{ij} \nabla \times n_j(\vec{r})$$

If $n=(0,f(x),0)$ the curl is $(0,0,f'(x))$.

If I rotate it $n' = (f(x)/ \sqrt{2},0,f(x)/ \sqrt{2})$ the curl is $(0,f(x)/ \sqrt{2},0)$
which is not the corresponding rotation of the original curl.

Comment: Linear maps don't commute, in general. Consider matrix multiplication.

Comment: You're right, I don't know why my intuition was that they commuted.

Comment: @TomásAlvim, perhaps your intuition was coming from the fact that a rotation $R$ is an isometry (preserves lengths and angles). In this case, the relevant way to change the vector field $X$ is to look at the so-called pushforward $R_{*} X$ which at $(x,y,z)$ is given by $R X(R^{-1}(x,y,z))$. The relation one gets is commutativity: $\nabla \times R_{*} X = R_{*} \nabla \times X$.

Comment: I tried to calculate curl $R n R^{-1}$, then  R (curl n) R^-1 and it was different, but it might be my mistake.